# ebay API - UploadSiteHostedPictures - POST upload error : Attachment request file is missing

Tags: xml, post, mime, ebay-api

Well I know its a long shot but after about 4 hours of searching and trying I am about to give up... 
Cant figure it out how to send a POST request with a base64 encoded image attached to it.
I am building an application that will automatically list items on eBay and I am stuck on the uploading image phase. basically what I need to do(according ebay documentation) is do the following:

> If you are using binary attachments (instead of external picture URLs), you must upload them using XML version 1.0. To include the picture as a binary MIME attachment, send it after the XML input in the same POST request.

I am new to this field so before coding it on python I am trying to see how it works via postman, here is my request:

The headers:

```
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 967
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: UploadSiteHostedPictures
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="MIME_boundary"
X-EBAY-API-VERSION: 967
```

the body:

```
--MIME_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XML Payload"
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>mysecrettoken</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>
--MIME_boundary

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
--MIME-boundray--
```

The result is: "Attachment request file is missing"
witch means that ebay doesnt recognize the 64base encoded image

Comment: Have you resolved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After 2nd `--MIME_boundary` there should be headers describing content as well. For example

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"`- to indicate it is a file attached to the form.

and
`Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` - to indicate it as base64 encoded and not raw binary data.

See https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1092 for full example.

Answer (score 0):

The body has to be multipart.
Part1: opening XML-Tag with requester-Credentials as text/utf-8
Part2: your JPG-file buffered as BINARY!!
Part3: kind of "end-sequence" as text/utf-8

Then you have to concat Part1,Part2,Part3 together. This is your final body for your request.

I followed an example from:
https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/07/27/multipart-post-request-using-node.js/

Works like a charm!

You'll get an ebay response with `<FullURL>, <BaseURL> and <MemberURL>`.
These URLs you have to catch/save for further purposes, if needed...

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2024, and I had the pleasure of digging around the internet for a few weeks and also found difficulty in coming up with a solution. It seems I've finally figured out a way to get something working, so here's the code sample that worked for me:

```
let boundary = "--FormBoundary\(UUID().uuidString)--"
let newLine = "\r\n"

var request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-SITEID")
request.addValue("967", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL")
request.addValue(appName, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME")
request.addValue(devID, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME")
request.addValue(certID, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME")    
request.addValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-DETAIL-LEVEL")
request.addValue("UploadSiteHostedPictures", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME")
request.addValue(
    "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)",
    forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"
)
    
var body = Data()
    
body.append("\(boundary)")
body.append(newLine)
body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image.png\"")
body.append(newLine)
body.append("Content-Type: application/xml")
body.append(newLine)
body.append(newLine)
let bodyString = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>\(authToken)</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <PictureSet>Standard</PictureSet>
    <ExtensionInDays>20</ExtensionInDays>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>
"""
body.append(bodyString)
body.append(newLine)
body.append(newLine)

body.append(newLine)
body.append("\(boundary)")
body.append(newLine)
body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.png\"")
body.append(newLine)
body.append("Content-Type: image/png")
body.append(newLine)
body.append(newLine)
body.append(imageData)
body.append(newLine)
body.append(newLine)

body.append("\(boundary)")
body.append(newLine)

let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: body, completionHandler: { [weak self] responseData, response, error in
    // handle response 
})
        
task.resume()
```

I'm sure there's probably a bunch of stuff in the code that looks weird to anyone who actually knows what they're doing, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

I also had an XML parsing issue response that took me a while to figure out because I had an empty line in the first line of my body, just in case that happens to anyone else.

Anyways, hope this helps out somebody in the universe.